# Convert multiple PDFs to TXT

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, converters

I would like to convert hundreds of PDF files (of varying formatting and sizes) to txt and have struggled to find a layman's option for this.

What is the best way to do this?
I have tried some pre-packaged software (PDF2Text Pilot) but it just... didn't work.

I also followed a guide to do so in python, but couldn't seem to get python to open from the right directory as I am not too knowledgeable in this area.

What method would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the shell `pdftotext` command from the [`poppler`](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) utils if you are not apposed to not using python. It works shockingly well for digital PDFs. You could then run

```
find /path/to/pdfs -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 pdftotext
```

in your shell to get all the text versions of the pdfs. This will be quite fast. You could run this command from python with [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if necessary.

```
import subprocess
command = 'find /path/to/pdfs -name \'*.pdf\' -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 pdftotext'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print(process.returncode)
```

I think this will be faster and simpler than going with a native python approach - but I can provide one if necessary.

Comment: That sounds interesting! I am a big newbie with python though, is that easy to install etc? @modesitt

Comment: yes - quite. what operating system are you on @Lewis?